# How to hide an URL/SRC from iframe?

Tags: php, url, iframe, hide

Is there anyone that know a clever way to hide the src of an iframe?

```
<iframe src=
    "<?php 
      $values = get_post_custom_values("my-custom-field"); 
      echo $values[0]; 
    ?>" 
    width="100%" 
    height="500px" 
    frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Comment: No, not without obfuscating some javascript to inject that iframe into the page in the first place. But this isn't a very nice thing to do. An anyone who can open up their browser tools can see what's loaded anyway.

Comment: Why not just eliminate the iframe completely and use more creative  JavaScript + css approach

Comment: The browser *needs* the `src`. No `src`, no iframe. You cannot hide something as essential as the URL where the data is.

Comment: Just to echo the above 2 comments, if you provide an abridged version of your code, people may have suggestions on how you could improve your design

Comment: My code is the code above. I´m gonna use Wordpress and the URL will be updated trough custom fields

Comment: I´m very open for alternatives. i.e. PHP code? Ive tried `include '/folder/index.php';` but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: *Why* do you want an iframe? Where is the data coming from? What is the data showing that a normal PHP include couldn't?

Comment: The thing is. The file I want to include contains an online course delivered from another company. Content is unchangable at this moment. So I need to include this file in to a webside and then hide the src URL so people cant pass it along, because the course is paid course. So no need for iframe, but figured that was a good way. The course has alot of included files in it so i cant just include it with php. Then I need all related files too, and thats like 200 files. Sorry for the bad english and typos

Comment: If the data is ***publicly available***, regardless of whether it's through an iframe or not, people will always be able to pass it on somehow if they really want to.

Comment: ok, what about htaccess command to deny direct access top the folder the source file is in? but accept access for the iframe?

Comment: It is not possible! Either the data can be accessed by anybody or it cannot. Either way it has to be accessed through a URL, because that's how the web works.

Comment: ok i see... ineed to edit the course it self to make it work with my CMS. Thanks you all for tht nice tries :)

Answer (score -1):

As people have said in the comments, something which the browser requires cannot be hidden.

The only thing I can think of that comes close is using HTML Entities:

```
<iframe src=
    "<?php 
      echo htmlentities($myurl);
    ?>" 
    width="100%" 
    height="500px" 
    frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Sorry but if there was a better way coded into actual browsers then it could be possible. This is probably the closest you're going to get though.